# Geometric Progression using Recursion (Java)

Tags: java, recursion, factorial

I have an assignment for class where I need to write a method which calculates a Geometric progression for *n* integers using recursion.

The value of *n* is received from the user.

```
public static float Geometric(float n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    else 
    {
        if(n == 1)
            System.out.println(n); 
        else    
            return (n * Geometric(n-1)); 
    }
}
```

The code works fine, until the value of *n* exceeds 34. Then, the method starts returning wrong answers. I'm assuming it has to do with the maximum value that a float can hold.

Is there a way to calculate/store values that exceed the maximum value of the primitive data types?

It seems to me that recursion isn't a good way to calculate a geometric progression, but maybe I'm just missing something. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you any idea about tail recursion ?

Comment: `double` will hold more than `float`.. or use `long` if you only need integers and not decimal numbers

Comment: what is the common ratio and first term og geometric progression ?

Comment: `2^32-1` is the max number for `integer` datatype, and factorial grows much faster than exponential. `34!` is indeed outside of 'integer' range, it's even beyond `long` datatype which is max `2^64-1`. For anything larger `BigInteger` is needed. In your case, given that you have floating point numbers, it's similar, just that `BigDecimal` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

For dealing with massive numbers, you can try looking at [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) or [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class. There is also another StackOverflow question ([Finding the factorial using recursion with the BigInteger Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908260/finding-the-factorial-using-recursion-with-the-biginteger-class)) that should be quite similar to your case